# node-fetch invalid header token

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api, node-fetch

this is the code i tried to run but I am constantly getting same error. If I remove cookie from headers it works but I need cookies just like this format.`"cookie": "username=admin"`

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

fetch("http://192.168.1.254/config/log_off_page.htm", {
  insecureHTTPParser: true,
  "headers": {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,tr;q=0.8",
    "cache-control": "max-age=0",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "cookie": "username=admin",
    "Referer": "http://192.168.1.254/config/log_off_page.htm",
    "Referrer-Policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
  },
  "body": "restoreUrl=&errorCollector=&userName%24query=admin&password%24query=pass",
  "method": "POST"
});
```

this package.json

```
{
  "name": "x",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --insecure-http-parser index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "http-parser-js": "^0.5.8",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.10",
    "node-libcurl": "^2.3.4"
  }
}
```

run

```
node --insecure-http-parser index.js
```

this is the error ...

```
file:///Users/absolutzer0/projects/x/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:108
                        reject(new FetchError(`request to ${request.url} failed, reason: ${error.message}`, 'system', error));
                               ^

FetchError: request to http://192.168.1.254/config/log_off_page.htm failed, reason: Parse Error: Invalid header token
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///Users/absolutzer0/projects/x/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:108:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at Socket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:503:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN',
  code: 'HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN',
  erroredSysCall: undefined
}
```

what I tried:

- adding `--insecure-http-parser` to npm start script
- trying different libs like Axios etc. but I think this problem is not about a lib.
- adding `insecureHTTPParser: true` to options.

but i am not able to run it .

Comment: do you have a backend route for that? If yes does it check the request and the cookie field?

Comment: Copying this fetch from dev tools there is also copy as curl option. If I copy as curl and run it from terminal, it works . I think it is about HTTP parser thing of nodejs.